# Lumia 950 XL voice dictation icon missing

Tags: windows-10-mobile, keyboard, lumia-950-xl, speech

The little microphone icon that used to appear above the keyboard has disappeared I believe soon after Windows update.
This was very handy when I've been sending text message. Does anybody out there know how I could have the feature reactivated?

Answer (score 2):

In the settings > keyboard section, there is a button "More keyboard settings".

In that section, make sure that "Show dictation button" is checked.

By Default, it is unchecked.

What language are you using? I am using German and I have no option for dictation.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with my Lumia 650 but eventually fixed it as follows:

Settings
Privacy
Speech, Inking & Typing
Getting to know you
Click on getting to know me and the dictation icon reappears - hooray!

Comment: Though it is not directly related with dictation icon visibilty, yet it works for me as well....